# Select command doing wrong calculation for a specific table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

So our teacher taught us how to use the select command in MySQl to do calculations on data available in columns and first it was to calculate to total of all subjects which were 5 and it yielded correct result but when i try to find the percentage for the same , it is giving me wrong answer. i tried putting division first, then multiplication and then put multiplication first and then division, still the answer is wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.
i have put the images down here.
[image]

Comment: ok so a little bit of info, i have forgot to put as percentage when calculating percentage but i did put as total when calculating for total as shown in picture, but i went back and added as percentage but the answer was same except the column name was now percentage instead of the big name you see above but other than that no change.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Rather, it's better to put each portion of that image into code block (use the `{}` icon on the toolbar to help format) so that others can copy the queries and/or other information to help assist.

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone stumbling on this problem, I found the solution today. It is to put brackets after adding all the subjects and then dividing and multiplying. It's kind of like Bodmas' rule, where the equation in the bracket gets solved first and those outside of the bracket are solved last.Also thanks to Paul for his suggestion to put it in the code block instead of images. I will keep that in mind in the future.
Like the code below:

```
mysql> select (accounts+hindi+english+bst+computer)/500*100 as percentage from result;
+------------+
| percentage |
+------------+
|  78.406001 |
|  76.326000 |
|  76.326000 |
|  76.326000 |
|  76.326000 |
+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```